# Sinopia(Local NPM registry)-Database

Tags: node.js, npm, repository, sinopia

[Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia) seems so cool for having a local npm registry. I have a couple of questions in terms o f this module:

Sinopia Documentation says "Sinopia keeps its own small database"; so what database is being used?

On the other hand it is mentioned "If you want to use a database instead, ask for it, we'll come up with some kind of a plugin system." So is any database being used or not? Is there any plugin which uses the database and they mentioned now? It seems that now all info is being saved in config.yaml as opposed to a DB, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sinopia saves repositories directly in filesystem as you can see [here](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/blob/0d266be9652d6524d085a46dc5d6ed319a35b99e/lib/local-storage.js) and the tokens/users are saved in a JSON file.
So, no, there is not a SQL or NoSQL database as you know it.

But you really don't need it, I'm using it with 30 devs on a small server and we haven't got any issue so far.

Comment: But dont you think we need a DB for monitoring (Some sort of statistics, download counts in different time intervals,...)?

Comment: You could store it un a JSON in the repo folder, and do you really care about stats on a private npm ? It's your projects, you should know them already.

Comment: I agree sinopia is great but it has some room to improve... It seems you have used it for a while for a team of 30; do you see any specific feature missing? I appreciate your feedback...

Comment: Most importnatly, didn you ever experience race condition when two devs publishing? Since they are using file system as opposed to Database, is the operation ACID?

Comment: 2 devs never publish the same package at the same time, there is a team responsible for a package and they communicate about publishing it. We've been totally satisfied with it. Something we didnt do was the user/role thing because it didnt look userfriendly (we have 1 user for everyone), also the interface is not beautiful but i only use npm cli (should've been 3 months since i last used it).

Comment: So does that mean you are aware of a race condition issue for this module and that's why never let two devs publish the same package at the same time?